# Javascript validation for ñÑ characters works on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on ASP.Net, i have a WebForm with a link to a javascript file which contains the following function:

```
    $(".string").keydown(function (e) {
    var x = (e.charCode) ? e.charCode : ((e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode);
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 27, 16, 13, 32, 192, 9, 209, 241]) !== -1 ||
        (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode == 67 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode == 88 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This successfully allows me to type the ñÑ (209, 241) characters on Chrome but fails to do so on Firefox, i saw that you should use `e.which` when dealing with Firefox but it doesn't work. I'm not too good with javascript so, what am i not understanding here?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the FF debugger and inspecting the value of e.keyCode after pressing the ñ and Ñ characters?

Comment: It simply returns 0 in both cases, but it seems to recognize e.key = 'ñ' - soooorry for the ultra late reply, some work piled up

Answer (score 1):

With the help of mister Lee Jenkins I realized fixing my code like this was enough to fix the issue, thx a lot! Just needed to add `(e.key == "ñ" || e.key == "Ñ") ||`

```
$(".string").keydown(function (e) {
    var x = (e.charCode) ? e.charCode : ((e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode);
    if ($.inArray(x, [46, 8, 27, 16, 13, 32, 192, 9, 209, 241]) !== -1 ||
        (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode == 67 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode == 88 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.keyCode == 88 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        (e.key == "ñ" || e.key == "Ñ") ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution!